# bash + lookup + doing a lookup on 1 file to feed another

Tags: bash, lookup

this is a file with the country name and lat and long:

```
$ cat country_with_lat_long
country,latitude,longitude,name,countrycode
AU,-25.274398,133.775136,Australia,Unknown
CN,35.86166,104.195397,China,Unknown
DE,51.165691,10.451526,Germany,Unknown
FR,46.227638,2.213749,France,Unknown
NZ,-40.900557,174.885971,New Zealand,Unknown
WS,-13.759029,-172.104629,Samoa,Unknown
CH,46.818188,8.227512,Switzerland,Unknown
US,37.09024,-95.712891,United States,Unknown
VU,-15.376706,166.959158,Vanuatu,Unknown
```

this is the file with the int code

```
$ cat country_with_code
name,code
Australia,61
China,86
France,33
Germany,49
New Zealand,64
Samoa,685
Switzerland,41
United Kingdom,44
United States,1
Vanuatu,678
```

**how do i do a vlookup in bash so i can get the code from `country_with_code` and match it to the country in the `country_with_lat_long` file in the `countrycode` column?**

**EDIT1 Trying to understand the answer below better for my reference alone if anything**

-F  = The Input Field Separator Variable 
-v  = ?? required before each assignment 
OFS     = The Output Field Separator Variable 
NR  = The FNR variable contains the number of lines read, but is reset for each file read. The NR variable accumulates for all files read 
FNR = see [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-16) 
code[$1]= loads field2 from country_with_code into an array indexed by field1
$2  = this is field2 of this file country_with_code 
$4  = ?? think this is field 4 in country_with_lat_long 
$NF = The Number of Fields Variable, think this is the field I want to write to in the `country_with_lat_long` file in this case $5 
code[$4]= ??

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`join`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/join.1.html) command, but since the files aren't sorted, it gets a bit messy.

Here's awk

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    NR == FNR {code[$1] = $2; next} 
    $4 in code {$NF = code[$4]} 
    {print}
' country_with_code  country_with_lat_long
```

```
country,latitude,longitude,name,code
AU,-25.274398,133.775136,Australia,61
CN,35.86166,104.195397,China,86
DE,51.165691,10.451526,Germany,49
FR,46.227638,2.213749,France,33
NZ,-40.900557,174.885971,New Zealand,64
WS,-13.759029,-172.104629,Samoa,685
CH,46.818188,8.227512,Switzerland,41
US,37.09024,-95.712891,United States,1
VU,-15.376706,166.959158,Vanuatu,678
```

Comment: tks care to give a comment on the paramaters?

Comment: also what if a country is not in one of the lists?